# Application icon not transferred to Android device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to deploy my application with Android 2.1 features. I placed an application icon in PNG format in the drawable-ldpi,and drawable-hdpi folders. When I installed to the device, it is not showing the application icon on the home screen of the device.

Please help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Show us your androidmanifest.xml... also, how is the icon image named?

Comment: If you place the image on the `drawable` folder, does it work?

Comment: Hi, Cristian, Macarse Its working some how. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem like this before.

My app wasn't changing name and icon, even with everything changed in manifest and icons in drawable folders.

It seems like it had some sort of cache, which installed the same old config (although coding was changing).

Restarting the phone solved my problem.